# How to stop variable in for loop from being passed by reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am assigning onclicks that contain the number that the link is on the page. This is my code:

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var t = 0; t < aTags.length; t++){

    var aTag = aTags[t];

    aTag.onclick = function(){setSubMenu(t);};


}


function setSubMenu(t){

    console.log("t: " + t);
    //The issue is t is always evaluating to the length of aTags
    //instead of the current tag. 

}
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a self-executing closure:

```
for (var t = 0; t < aTags.length; t++)(function(t) {

    var aTag = aTags[t];

    aTag.onclick = function() { setSubMenu(t); };

})(t);
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Will mark it as answer if anything cleaner does not come up.

Comment: This is clean, and I'm pretty sure the only way. You want your t's to be evaluated when the inside `function` object is created, not when it's executed.